# Generating a ranges::view from a raw pointer (decayed C style array) and a size

Tags: c++, range-v3

Using a function from a C library providing a pointer and a size, is there (or will there be) a way to generate a ranges::view directly from it ?
As I understood, views need a begin iterator and a sentinel, so will I have to copy the content of the decayed C array into a vector to be able to use views in that case ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wont need to make any sort of copy.  Along with ranges, C++20 will also have [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) which takes a pointer and a size and treats it as a container.  You can then pass that to all of the ranges functions.  That would look like

```
std::size_t size;
auto ptr = c_function_call(&size); // or however you get the pointer and size from the c function
std::span container{ptr, size};
// use container with any view you want here
```

Comment: Yes nice solution, I forgot to mention that I'm using msvc 2019 which doesn't implement `std::span`yet. I'll go for [martin moene's span-lite implementation](https://github.com/martinmoene/span-lite) which has a vcpkg package

Answer (score 4):

If `std::span` is not available, you can take advantage of the fact that a pointer *is* a C++ iterator.

Given a pointer `p` and a size `n`, you can use the pair of iterators [`p`, `p + n`) to construct a range using `ranges::subrange`:

```
void print(int i) { std::cout << i << " "; }

int values[6] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// Example of a pointer and a size.
const int* ptr = values;
const std::size_t n = 3;

auto r = ranges::subrange(ptr, ptr + n);
ranges::for_each(r, print);  // Prints:  0, 1, 2
```

Working example:  https://wandbox.org/permlink/eeIa96ieCb8GIQcM

Comment: Compared to the span solution is there one which will have less overhead ?
Does the range solution take ownership of the memory (unlike span) or can I directly constuct a view insead ?

Comment: Neither the direct approach here, nor the span approach, will take ownership of memory.  You will need to make sure that the lifetime of the pointed-to data exceeds the lifetime of the range.

Comment: I think both approaches (this one and the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58227115/1718575)  suggested by @NathanOliver) will have similar performance.  Internally, a span is simply a pointer and a size, and any extra calls to span member functions (e.g. `span<T>::begin()`) should be inlined/optimized out.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @NicholasM. I'm still a bit confused with the notion of "ranges" and "actions/views on ranges"... I guess I still have to learn :)

Comment: is it equivalent to [counted view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_counted) ?